# Reshaping a pandas dataframe by repeating rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to Python especially Pandas.
I have one dataframe like

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Id     Name    Salary    desc1     desc2     desc3
-----------------------------------------------------
1      ABC1    2000       x1        y1        z1
-----------------------------------------------------
2      ABC2    5000       x2        y1        z2
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to transform it into this way

```
-----------------------------------------
ID     Name     Salary      Variable
-----------------------------------------
1      ABC1      2000          x1
-----------------------------------------
1      ABC1      2000          y1
-----------------------------------------
1      ABC1      2000          z1  
-----------------------------------------
2      ABC2      5000          x2  
-----------------------------------------
2      ABC2      5000          y2  
-----------------------------------------
2      ABC2      5000          z2 
-----------------------------------------
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not  a code service. Take the [tour] and provide some [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Id','Name','Salary'])
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=3, drop=True)
       .reset_index(name='Variable')

print (df)
   Id  Name  Salary Variable
0   1  ABC1    2000       x1
1   1  ABC1    2000       y1
2   1  ABC1    2000       z1
3   2  ABC2    5000       x2
4   2  ABC2    5000       y1
5   2  ABC2    5000       z2
```

If sorting first 3 columns is not necessary:

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = df.melt(['Id','Name','Salary'], value_name='Variable').drop('variable', axis=1)
print (df)
   Id  Name  Salary Variable
0   1  ABC1    2000       x1
1   2  ABC2    5000       x2
2   1  ABC1    2000       y1
3   2  ABC2    5000       y1
4   1  ABC1    2000       z1
5   2  ABC2    5000       z2
```

[`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L857) is now undocumented, but is possible in future will by removed ([github link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003#issuecomment-324625271)).

```
df = pd.lreshape(df, {'Variable':['desc1','desc2','desc3']})
print (df)
   Id  Name  Salary Variable
0   1  ABC1    2000       x1
1   2  ABC2    5000       x2
2   1  ABC1    2000       y1
3   2  ABC2    5000       y1
4   1  ABC1    2000       z1
5   2  ABC2    5000       z2
```